# Multiple Google Sheet Query - Ways to reduce Load time

Tags: database, google-sheets

I am using a Google Sheet to do job costing for our company. I can do an export of our timesheet data and paste it into the first sheet (Master Timesheet Data) of the spreadsheet. On the second sheet (Job Costing) I have hundreds (thousands?) of query formulas looking up and summing data from the first tab.

Here are a few of the items that I am looking at:

- Total time spent (Master Timesheet Data, column L) on each individual project (Master Timesheet Data, column N). You can see this Query on the Job Costing sheet > Column AG
- Total Time per service item (Master Timesheet Data, column R) per each individual project. You can see these Query's on the Job Costing sheet > columns B - P.
- Total time per employee (Master Timesheet Data, column C) per each individual project. You can see these Query's on the Job Costing sheet > columns Q - AE

This sheet is very slow to load. Is there a way I could reduce the number of Query's?

[Google Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QCy-wM36O2W_rrW7r-23YuBQeOZxYM9S8FjYK9uqw2c/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just not use `QUERY`. I can't think of many times when a `QUERY` is better for a single cell than some built-in. And it looks like you have 10,000s of cells.

In this case, `SUMIFS` is the magic function. (Seconds to load instead of minutes)

B2 Formula:

```
=SUMIFS(
  'Master Timesheet Data'!$L$2:$L,
  'Master Timesheet Data'!$N$2:$N,"="&$A2,
  'Master Timesheet Data'!$R$2:$R,"="&B$1)
```

Q2 Formula:

```
=SUMIFS(
  'Master Timesheet Data'!$L$2:$L,
  'Master Timesheet Data'!$N$2:$N,"="&$A2,
  'Master Timesheet Data'!$C$2:$C,"="&Q$1)
```

AG Formula (just use `SUMIF` since we have a single criterion):

```
=SUMIF(
  'Master Timesheet Data'!$N$2:$N,
  "="&$A2,
  'Master Timesheet Data'!$L$2:$L)
```

It still involves dragging, though. Perhaps someone could find some single `ArrayFormula`s to do this, but note that I already tried to use the usual `TRANSPOSE` cross-compare trick. The resulting data set was too large.

I suppose another option would be to script your way to victory.

Comment: Amazing how much quicker that is! Thanks